# Xcode - Nested storyboard views - hide/show?

Tags: xcode

I have a reasonably complicated UIView which contains several nested views which are displayed according to a variety of responses - all are laid out in a storyboard.

Is there a way to hide a view in the foreground to work on a view in the background?  As its really fiddly selecting particular elements to arrange / style!?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what to do in this situation. Did you have any good ideas?

Comment: i so wish storyboard had a visible checkbox making it easier for us to work

Answer (score 3):

I've been trying to figure out a nice way to do this, some function like hiding the view and its subviews from the storyboard (not from the actual application), but couldn't find anything.

This is not the nicest of ways but it is how I do it at the moment...

What I do is select the views I want to "hide" from the document outline and add a constant (screen width/height) value to its x/y origin value to push them out of the screen. I also change the document label for those views (Identity Inspector > Document > Label) to something like "Hidden" so I can later search for the "hidden" views from the document outline and put them back where they belong.

Comment: hi @7usam - yep thats the only workaround I could find also - was thinking - 'surely i'm missing something here - there must be a way to hide / select' but i've found nowt!  Cheers

Answer (score 3):

I have 2 work arounds.

A) Change the View Controllers size to freeform.  Set its size to be really large so I can space out the views.

B) Use the sort order of the views Document Outline (lowest is front most) and add an image view (same as the view background) under the first view to block the others.  Then delete it after finishing my edits.

or xcode developers could just simple add a design-visible checkbox for views and controls.... but ill take my rants somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

In xcode 7 you can do it from the storybord

[image: un-chech installed]

for more details
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25213491/4879683

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you :

- Open your storyboard in the Finder and edit it with a simple text editor (not xcode).
  You will see it's just a xml file.Look for the view you want to hide, and add hidden="YES" in the parameters list. 
  That's what I do on my own project.
- In Xcode when you select your storyboard, you have a panel that displays all your view controllers and their hierarchy. If you change the order of the elements you change the background/foreground order.

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra views to the scene dock.

[image]

These views get initiated along with the view controller, but are not added to the view controller's view hierarchy. You can reference them using IBOutlets.

e.g. I have a full screen loading view that I added to the scene dock instead of covering up the view controller in the storyboard. I can add the loading view to the view controller's view hierarchy in code:

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var loadingView: UIView!

...

loadingView.frame = view.bounds
loadingView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth.union(UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight)
view.addSubview(loadingView)
```

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/AddViewsToDock.html