# hide elements in xcode storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Is there a way to hide elements in storyboard interface? What I am talking about is like in Photoshop how you can hide layers while working. I ask because I have some stacked items and it would be nice to not see everything at once while working sometimes.

Answer (score 69):

While selecting your view/object, in the right panel click the 'Installed' button.
Make you to reenable it when your done!

[image]

```
          ^
```

Make sure to select one of the views:

[image]

Comment: sorry I am using Xcode 6 Beta and do not see the "installed" button in the attributes inspector

Comment: The `Installed` button is only visible when your storyboard has `Use Auto Layout` enabled.

Comment: You can set Alpha to zero if AutoLayout is not enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I also cannot see the 'installed' checkbox (Xcode 6.4), but here is my workaround to temporarily hide a layer.

Select one of your views to 'hide' and in Utilities Pane, select Size inspector and set your X (horizontal) value to 1000 - which will slide the view off the screen, allowing you access to layers below. Don't forget to reset X value when done.

Answer (score 2):

The Installed button is visible after Xcode 6 and later, also enable "Use Auto Layout" and "Use Trait Variations".